# testing condition in matrix and vector

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, conditional-statements

I would like to check this matrix *m* if it is <= 1 or >= 10. if so, I would like to change the value of another vector, *val*. if *val* is "A", then it should be changed to "B" and vice versa. If *val* is "C" it should be changed to "D" and vice versa. If no value is <= 1 or >= 10 in the matrix *m* then it should return *val*.

```
m
     x y
[1,] 2 11
[2,] 4 6
[3,] 5 6
[4,] 0 6
[5,] 2 6

val = "A"
```

the output should therefore be

```
out 
"B"
```

What I currently have is the following

```
x = m[, 1]
y = m[, 2]

x.test = any(x <= 1)
x.test = cbind(x.test, any(x >= 10) )

y.test = any(y <= 1) 
y.test = cbind(y.test, any(y >= 10) ) 

 if (any(x.test)==TRUE || any(y.test)==TRUE && val == 'A')
  { val2 = 'B'
} else if (any(x.test)==TRUE || any(y.test)==TRUE && val == 'B') 
  { val2 = 'A'
} else if (any(x.test)==TRUE || any(y.test)==TRUE && val == 'C') 
  {val2 = 'D'
} else if (any(x.test)==TRUE || any(y.test)==TRUE && val == 'D') 
  {val2 = 'C'
} else { val2 = val }
```

but it seems cumbersome and does not work well…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a data frame which acts like a dictionary and help you find out the corresponding `val2` if condition is satisfied. At the meantime, you don't need to test each column of the matrix separately, one statement is enough just like a one D vector:

```
dicFrame <- data.frame(val = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), val2 = c("B", "A", "D", "C"), stringsAsFactors = F)

#  val val2
#1   A    B
#2   B    A
#3   C    D
#4   D    C

val = "A"
val2 = if(any(mat >= 10 | mat <= 1)) dicFrame[dicFrame$val == val, 'val2'] else val
val2
# [1] "B"
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Psidom's suggestion to use a lookup table, but to properly vectorize the solution, you need to use [`match()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html):

```
if (any(m<=1L | m>=10L)) map$value[match(val,map$key)] else val;
##  [1] "A" "A" "D" "C" "B" "C" "C" "D" "D" "B"
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(1L);
NV <- 10L; val <- sample(LETTERS[1:4],NV,T);
m <- matrix(c(2L,4L,5L,0L,2L,11L,6L,6L,6L,6L),5L);
map <- data.frame(key=c('A','B','C','D'),value=c('B','A','D','C'),stringsAsFactors=F);

val;
##  [1] "B" "B" "C" "D" "A" "D" "D" "C" "C" "A"
map;
##   key value
## 1   A     B
## 2   B     A
## 3   C     D
## 4   D     C
```

---

Also note that `==TRUE` is never necessary. If you already have a logical value, then it will already be true, in which case the comparison would leave it as true, or it will already be false, in which case the comparison would leave it as false (or it will already be NA, in which case the comparison would leave it as NA).

Comment: Good option with description.  Plus one.